# lookup missing values from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have two dataframes.

```
df1

col1 var1 var2 var3

X11            NA (for var3)

X12 NA (for var2)

X13  NA (for var1)
```

df1 has a few columns (float64 type representing some categories) like var1, var2, var3 with values between 1-5 for each and some missing values for the categories.

I want to fill in the missing values (in each of var1, var2, and var3 columns) using another dataframe, df2 such that df2 has a column with the value for the category.

```
df2

col1 col2   val col4

X11  var1   3   X11-X21

X12  var3   2   X21-X22

X13  var2   1   X13-X32
```

col4 is the concatenation of col1 and col2 but it did not help much.

How could I do this?
Since we need to look up on several columns and also because of the structure of df1, I found it complicated to use pivot or melt or even one-hot encoding (produces 5 columns each with _1 to _5 suffixed.
I also though about creating a set but then the pairs must be unique which is not the case.
Same when I thought of using dictionary as I cannot think of unique keys.

How could I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your inputs as DataFrame constructors for clarity, they are currently ambiguous.

Comment: what is the purpose of `col4` in `df2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below works with the small sample you provided.

The code goes through the rows of `df1`, reading out each row into the variable `row`. It then goes through the values (and column names) of `row`. When a value is `pd.NA`, it indexes into `df2` based on the index of `row`, and returns the `df2["val"]` at that index.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

#
# Create test data
#
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['X11', 'X12', 'X13'],
    'var1': [100, 200, pd.NA],
    'var2': [300, pd.NA, 400],
    'var3': [pd.NA, 500, 600]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['X11', 'X12', 'X13'],
    'col2': ['var3', 'var2', 'var1'],
    'val': [3, 2, 1],
})


#
# Solution
#
def fill_missing(row):
    idx = row.name #index of current row
    
    #Go over each entry in this row
    for col, value in row.items():
        if not pd.isna(value):
            continue
        #If NA, cross reference against df2
        # and overwrite the row's value
        col_to_fill = df2.loc[idx, 'col2']
        assert col_to_fill == col #should match if df2 is right about the NA locations
        val_to_fill = df2.loc[idx, 'val']
        row[col] = val_to_fill
    return row

# Apply the fill_missing function to each row in df1 using .apply(..., axis=1)
df1_filled = df1.copy().apply(fill_missing, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. but still trying to understand your code. What is the row that is passed to the function? The entire copy of df1? What if I did not want to apply the function to all columns of df1 but only to selected columns? Also, I am trying to convert the resulting float values to int. I tried to modify these lines to convert to int but it doesnt work. val_to_fill = df2.loc[idx, 'val'].astype(int) and row[col] = val_to_fill.astype(int)

Comment: @AmitAgarwal please provide as reproducible input as requested, and the exact expected output. If really this is what you want there are much more efficient approaches to perform this task.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal No problem. The way `.apply(fill_missing, axis=1)` works is that it will read out the rows one by one, each time passing it to `fill_missing`. So `fill_missing` gets the rows one at a time. For each row it gets, it will fill in the NA, and return the new row. Eventually all of `df1` will have been run through `fill_missing` on a row-wise basis. In terms of limiting it to selected columns, that can be done but the exact code will depend on your data. To convert to `int`, this is one way: `df1 = df1.convert_dtypes()`. It will choose an appropriate dtype that also supports `pd.NA`.